# Is there any generic TypeConvertor with good performance?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I am using the following generic method for type conversion at runtime. But it takes time and affects the performance a bit.

**For 381 values conversion it takes 9922.71 milliseconds**.

Is there any best way to improve this?

```
    public static void test()
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            var xi = Common.CoerceValue(typeof(Guid), typeof(string), null, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }

        watch.Stop();

        double timetaken = watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    }

public static object CoerceValue(Type desiredType, Type valueType, object oldValue, object value)
{
    if (desiredType.Equals(valueType))
    {
        // types match, just return value
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        if (desiredType.IsGenericType)
        {
            if (desiredType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                if (value == null)
                    return null;
               else if (valueType.Equals(typeof(string)) && System.Convert.ToString(value) == string.Empty)
                   return null;
             }

             desiredType = GetPropertyType(desiredType);
        }

        if (desiredType.IsEnum && (valueType.Equals(typeof(string)) || Enum.GetUnderlyingType(desiredType).Equals(valueType)))
            return System.Enum.Parse(desiredType, value.ToString());

        if ((desiredType.IsPrimitive || desiredType.Equals(typeof(decimal))) &&
                    valueType.Equals(typeof(string)) && string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
           value = 0;

        try
        {
            if (desiredType.Equals(typeof(string)) && value != null)
            {
                return value.ToString();
            }
            else if (desiredType.Equals(typeof(Boolean)) && valueType.Equals(typeof(string)))
            {
                return "1" == Convert.ToString(value) || "TRUE" == Convert.ToString(value).ToUpper1();
            }
            else
            {
                if (desiredType.Equals(typeof(Guid)) && DBUtility.DBType == Core.Enums.DataBaseType.ORACLE)
                {
                    TypeConverter cnv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(desiredType);
                        return cnv.ConvertFrom(value);
                }
                else
                    return Convert.ChangeType(value, desiredType);
             }
        }
        catch
        {
            TypeConverter cnv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(desiredType);
            if (cnv != null && cnv.CanConvertFrom(valueType))
                return cnv.ConvertFrom(value);
            else
                throw;
         }
     }
} 

public static Type GetPropertyType(Type propertyType)
{
    Type type = propertyType;
    if (type.IsGenericType &&
             (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)))
        return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
    return type;
}
```

Comment: If the code works and you want it to be reviewed for optimization, you should post this as a question on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: ok. I will post it in codereview.  Guid (string) to Guid conversion takes most of the time. almost 90% of time taken for this conversion.

Comment: @anand How many guids are you parsing? My computer can parse 2 million GUIDs per second using `Guid.Parse`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, in the function, when converting string to guid, there was conversion error occurs and handled in the catch block. which degrade performance. there were 121 guid conversion, threw 121 conversion errors :(. which caused the problem.

Comment: @anand Exceptions aren't *that* expensive if you have no debugger attached.

Comment: @CodesInChaos oh. I didnt know that. thanks for your info. I will check without debugger.

Answer (score 0):

There is bug in the code which threw conversion error for guid (string) to guid type.

```
return Convert.ChangeType(value, desiredType);
```

so while converting 121 guids got error and resolved in the catch block. after fix, now it takes few milliseconds.